# .Htaccess rewrite rules for main index.php in foldder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about some rules in `.htaccess`.

I want to put all my web pages in the `/pages/` folder, including `index.php`.

So to do this, here are my rules in `.htaccess`:

```
#root / to pages/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/index.php [L,QSA]

# if url is /index.php redirect /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

# if url is pages/index.php redirect /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/index\.php
RewriteRule ^pages/index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

# if url is pages/ redirect /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/
RewriteRule ^pages/$ / [R=301,L]
```

But my question is... There are 4 rules for `index.php`.. so are the rules good? I have small doubts

It seems to work but can we simplify it?

Comment: "I want to put **all my web pages** in the `/pages/` folder, including `index.php`" - The "problem" with your existing rules is that they only move `index.php` to `/pages/` - not "all web pages". Presumably you do have other file requests that need to be rewritten to `/pages/`? (Yet, you say "it seems to work"?) And `/pages/` should presumably not be in the visible URL for **all** requests?

Comment: Yes, thoses 4 rules are only for index.php... the other pages are all url rewriting so i will place them in /pages/ folder. Example of a rule for contact page : RewriteRule ^contact-us pages/contact-us.php [QSA,L] .

Comment: can i simplify the 4 rules for index.php ? thank you :)